# Why might Wireshark and NodeJS disagree about a packet's contents?

Tags: node.js, networking

I'm working with [raw-socket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-socket) (a node module for sending raw data out on the network) and playing with their Ping example.

I have Wireshark set up to monitor traffic. I can see my ICMP packet go out, and a response comes back.

Here's where things get strange.

Wireshark shows the following packet:

```
IP:   4500003c69ea00004001e2fec0a85647c0a85640
ICMP: 00004b5200010a096162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f7071727374757677616263646566676869
```

However, the node event handler that fires when data comes in is showing:

```
IP:   4500280069ea00004001e2fec0a85647c0a85640
ICMP: 00004b5200010a096162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f7071727374757677616263646566676869
```

The ICMP components match. However, bytes 0x02 and 0x03 (the Length bytes) differ.
Wireshark shows 0x003c or 60 bytes (as expected).
Node shows 0x2800 or 10kB... which is not what is expected.

Notably, the checksum (bytes 0x18 and 0x19) are the same in each case, although it's only valid for the Wireshark packet.

So, here's the question: what might lead to this discrepancy? I'm inclined to believe Wireshark is correct since 60 bytes is the right size for an ICMP reply, but why is Node wrong here?

### OSX note

The docs for this module point out that, on OSX, it will try to use `SOCK_DGRAM` if `SOCK_RAW` is not permitted. I have tried this with that function disabled and using `sudo` and got the same responses as before.

### Github issue

It looks like https://github.com/nospaceships/node-raw-socket/issues/60 is open for this very issue, but it remains unclear if this is a code bug or a usage problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a FreeBSD bug (feature?) which subtracts the length of the IP header from the IP length header field and also flips it to host byte order.

[https://cseweb.ucsd.edu//~braghava/notes/freebsd-sockets.txt](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu//%7Ebraghava/notes/freebsd-sockets.txt)